# find the norm of v, a unit vector that has the same direction as v, and a unit vector that is oppositely directed to v.

Tags: geometry

(a) $v=(4,-3)$

that's what I have done so far:

$\|v\|=\sqrt{4^2+(-3)^2 }= 5$

and then I don't know how to find a unit vector. The only thing I know about the unit vector is a vector norm 1 is called a unit vector.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: if $v\neq0$ then $\frac{v}{\|v\|}$ has length $1$ and the same direction as $v$.

Comment: Um....so the unit vector = v // ||v|| so the answer is [3/13, -2/13], right?

Comment: I don't see how $\frac 15(4,-3)$ equals $(3/13,-2/13)$, but it's early in the morning here, maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: yeah, you're right. I think the answer is gonna be +-[4/5,-3/5]. Thanks :)

Comment: The answer in your case (opposite direction) is $(-4/5,3/5)$.